# OpenCV Mat to IplImage* conversion

Tags: opencv

I have a pointer to image:

```
IplImage *img;
```

which has been converted to `Mat`

```
Mat mt(img);
```

Then, the `Mat` is sent to a function that gets a reference to `Mat` as input `void f(Mat &m);`

```
f(mt);
```

Now I want to copy back the `Mat` data to the original image.

Do you have any suggestion?

Best
Ali

Comment: The conversion `Mat mt(img)` does not do any copying of the imagedata, so you don't have to do anything, as long as you don't do an operation which reallocates (eg. assign mt to an independent other Mat).

Answer (score 2):

Your answer can be found in the documentation here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html

Edit:

The first half of the first code area indeed talks about the copy constructor which you already have.

The second half of the first code area answers your question. Reproduced below for clarity.

```
//Convert to IplImage or CvMat, no data copying
IplImage ipl_img = img;
CvMat cvmat = img; // convert cv::Mat -> CvMat
```

Comment: The cheat sheet just talked about copy constructor and not what I am looking for. I have an already filled image and a Mat which should be copied to the data-part of the image. BTW thanks for answering.

Comment: A pointer to IplImage has been passed to a function. Inside the function a Mat has been filled by some data. If I just use *ipl_image = mat; no data will be copied and just there will be a header conversion and when I return from the function, since Mat memory space is released, the pointer to it is also useless. I am looking for something like ipl_img->copy(Mat) that copy the Mat data which has the same size of the image into the ipl_image data.

Comment: In fact, this is my code: `code` `int test(IplImage **srcImage, int num_images) 
{ 
    vector<Mat> images(num_images); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < num_images; ++i) 
    { 
        images[i] = Mat(srcImage[i]); // I guess this is correct! 
          .... 
         // some manipulation on images[i] 
     } 
    for (int i = 0; i < num_images; ++i) 
    { 
        srcImage[i] = ?????? 
     } }`

Comment: something like this should work but I am looking for a standard way   `for (int i = 0; i < num_images; ++i) 
    { 
        cvReleaseImage(&srcImage[i]); 
        srcImage[i] = new IplImage(images[i]); 
     } }`

Answer (score 1):

For the following case:

```
double algorithm(IplImage* imgin)
{
    //blabla
    return erg;
}
```

I use the following way to call the function:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image.bmp");
double erg = algorithm(&image.operator IplImage());
```

I have made some tests and how it looks the image object will manage the memory. The operator `IplImage()` will only construct the header for `IplImage`. Maybe this could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form:

Your Code:

> plImage *img;
>
> Mat mt(img);
>
> f(mt);

Now copy back the Mat data to the original image.

> img->imageData = (char *) mt.data;

You can also copy the data instead of pointer:

> memcpy(mt.data, img->imageData, (mt.rows*mt.cols));

(mt.rows*mt.cols) is the size that you should use for copy all data the mt to img.

Hope I helped